# Wordpress display/hide content based on date/time without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, display, recurring-events, timed

I have searched high and low looking for a plugin or code to show or hide content on a WordPress page based on the date and time without refreshing the page.  I can rig something and have the page refresh at a certain time, but the users watching the live stream would see an interruption.  It is also hard to find something that works on a recurring basis.

The content also needs to be recurring, so I need something like this: Show text "A" from 11:00 until 13:00 every Sunday and text "B" at all other times.  I know this is possible, but I cannot find the right combination of code to make it happen.